# RecyclerView adapter gets string from model as a memory object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have pretty normal recyclerview adapter. I pass the list of array to the adapter and trying set images from link as needed with Glide.

Problem is, when I try to get images link with loggin they seem normal, but when I pass data list to adapter they are not working. And giving memory object instead of String.

I should get this:
http://somelin.com/image.jpg

Instead I get this: 
package.name.models.responses.chain.Logo_@c170923

What should I do? My adapter works normally as I am using this adapter in other places in the same way and it works.

My adapter

```
public class ChainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Restaurant> modelList;

private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public ChainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Restaurant> modelList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.modelList = modelList;
}

public void updateList(ArrayList<Restaurant> modelList) {
    this.modelList = modelList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_chain_list, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //Here you can fill your row view
    if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        final Restaurant model = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder genericViewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

        String link = "http://cdn.link.in/unsafe/" + model.getLogo();
        System.out.println("chainAdapter " + link);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(link).into(genericViewHolder.rest_logo);
        CenteredImageSpan imagespan = new CenteredImageSpan(mContext, R.drawable.verified_account);

        Spannable text = new SpannableString(model.getName() + "  ");
        text.setSpan(imagespan, model.getName().length(), model.getName().length() + 1, 0); //text is an object of TextView

        if (model.getVerified()) {
            genericViewHolder.rest_name.setText(text);
        } else {
            genericViewHolder.rest_name.setText(model.getName());
        }

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        List<Today> hours = model.getToday();
        for (Today hour : hours) {
            if (hour.getWeekday() == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1) {
                genericViewHolder.restCloseNowIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_open_now);
                genericViewHolder.restCloseNowText.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.open_now));
                genericViewHolder.restCloseNowText.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.open_now));
            } else {
                genericViewHolder.restCloseNowIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_now);
                genericViewHolder.restCloseNowText.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.close_now));
                genericViewHolder.restCloseNowText.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.close_now));
            }
        }

        int totalRatings = model.getTotalRatings();

        if (totalRatings != 0)
            genericViewHolder.restStars.setText((int) totalRatings + "");
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return modelList.size();
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

private Restaurant getItem(int position) {
    return modelList.get(position);
}


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position, Restaurant model);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.imageView8)
    ImageView rest_logo;
    @BindView(R.id.textView3)
    TextView rest_name;
    @BindView(R.id.isVerified)
    ImageView isVerified;
    @BindView(R.id.rest_close_now_icon)
    ImageView restCloseNowIcon;
    @BindView(R.id.rest_close_now_text)
    TextView restCloseNowText;
    @BindView(R.id.rest_stars)
    TextView restStars;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> mItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition(), modelList.get(getAdapterPosition())));

    }
}
}
```

Model

```
public class Restaurant implements Parcelable
{

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("total_ratings")
@Expose
private Integer totalRatings;
@SerializedName("verified")
@Expose
private Boolean verified;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("logo")
@Expose
private Logo_ logo;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("today")
@Expose
private List<Today> today = null;
@SerializedName("thumbnail")
@Expose
private Thumbnail thumbnail;
public final static Creator<Restaurant> CREATOR = new Creator<Restaurant>() {


    @SuppressWarnings({
        "unchecked"
    })
    public Restaurant createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Restaurant(in);
    }

    public Restaurant[] newArray(int size) {
        return (new Restaurant[size]);
    }

}
;

protected Restaurant(Parcel in) {
    this.username = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.totalRatings = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.verified = ((Boolean) in.readValue((Boolean.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.name = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.logo = ((Logo_) in.readValue((Logo_.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.id = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
    in.readList(this.today, (Today.class.getClassLoader()));
    this.thumbnail = ((Thumbnail) in.readValue((Thumbnail.class.getClassLoader())));
}

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 * 
 */
public Restaurant() {
}

/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * @param logo
 * @param username
 * @param thumbnail
 * @param verified
 * @param name
 * @param today
 * @param totalRatings
 */
public Restaurant(String username, Integer totalRatings, Boolean verified, String name, Logo_ logo, Integer id, List<Today> today, Thumbnail thumbnail) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.totalRatings = totalRatings;
    this.verified = verified;
    this.name = name;
    this.logo = logo;
    this.id = id;
    this.today = today;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Integer getTotalRatings() {
    return totalRatings;
}

public void setTotalRatings(Integer totalRatings) {
    this.totalRatings = totalRatings;
}

public Boolean getVerified() {
    return verified;
}

public void setVerified(Boolean verified) {
    this.verified = verified;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Logo_ getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(Logo_ logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Today> getToday() {
    return today;
}

public void setToday(List<Today> today) {
    this.today = today;
}

public Thumbnail getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(Thumbnail thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(username);
    dest.writeValue(totalRatings);
    dest.writeValue(verified);
    dest.writeValue(name);
    dest.writeValue(logo);
    dest.writeValue(id);
    dest.writeList(today);
    dest.writeValue(thumbnail);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return  0;
}

}
```

Model Logo_

```
public class Logo_ implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("path")
@Expose
private String path;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("caption")
@Expose
private String caption;
public final static Creator<Logo_> CREATOR = new Creator<Logo_>() {


    @SuppressWarnings({
        "unchecked"
    })
    public Logo_ createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Logo_(in);
    }

    public Logo_[] newArray(int size) {
        return (new Logo_[size]);
    }

}
;

protected Logo_(Parcel in) {
    this.path = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.id = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.caption = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
}

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 * 
 */
public Logo_() {
}

/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * @param path
 * @param caption
 */
public Logo_(String path, Integer id, String caption) {
    super();
    this.path = path;
    this.id = id;
    this.caption = caption;
}

public String getPath() {
    return this.path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(path);
    dest.writeValue(id);
    dest.writeValue(caption);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return  0;
}

}
```

Comment: post your adapter code please

Comment: I updated post with adapter @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: Can we see your model as well, please?

Comment: I updated post with model too @LeviAlbuquerque thanks for the interest I hope you will help me.

Comment: Checkout the answer :) If you need more help, please provide the Logo_ POJO class as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered the problem is in this line:

```
String link = "YOUR_URL" + model.getLogo();
```

Your method getLogo() does not return a string to be appended here, but rather an object of type `Logo_`. You have 3 options:

1. Change the method getLogo in your model to return a String (probably the logo filename).
2. In the Logo object, create another method to return the name and call it like this:

   `String link = "YOUR_URL" + model.getLogo().getFilename();`

3.Override the toString method in your Logo object to return the filename.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.filename;
}
```

Edit: You can use the getPath() in your logo POJO:

```
String link = "YOUR_URL" + model.getLogo().getPath();
```

Comment: can u please edit and delete the link i forget to, thank u, I'll try now it and inform u

Comment: Did as u told me, but the same result again. (thank u for deleting)

Comment: addded Logo_ POJO class too

Comment: Thank u very very much. You saved my day.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: I was just blind to not to see it :/